# Override ActionMailer defaults with a method called from inside any mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

Given we have a custom header set in application.rb as

`config.action_mailer.default_options = { 
    'X-MyCustomHeader' => "Default_value" }`

I would like to be able to call a method, such as `remove_custom_header`from inside any mailer and it have the header removed, or at least set to nil.

Because its a custom header (starting with X-) ActionMailer will allow more than one to be created rather than reseting it as it would with standard headers.

What is the best way to define a method that can overide it?

The issue i have is that is you call `headers['X-MyCustomHeader'] = nil`inside the mailer method it will not override it, it simply creates a second header where the entry is nil, leaving the original from application.rb on the email.

The only way i can find to override the default set there is to call `default 'X-MyCustomHeader' => nil` inside the ApplicationMailer (or in any inheriting mailers class'), like below, but not in the method.

```
    class ApplicatioMailer < ActionMailer::Base
       helper :application
       default 'X-MyCustomHeader' => nil
     end
```

but i would like to call this on a method basis, not in the mailer class itself as the app has many many mailer classes and im looking to disable this for one or 2 methods in some of the Mailers.

My current solution is:

```
      class ApplicatioMailer < ActionMailer::Base
        helper :application
        default 'X-MyCustomHeader' => Proc.new { @is_disabled ? nil : Rails.config.action_mailer.default_header }

        def remove_custom_header
          @is_disabled = true
        end
      end
```

and this seems to work as you are using the `default` call from ActionMailer to override. Now i have tested this and it does work with multiple calls, so  the value of `@is_disabled`does not seem to persist between mailer calls. I dont understand how the class var works here, in a SuperClass of the mailer that calls it and when no new object of the class is created, but it seems to be null every new call to the ApplicationMailer, so for me it works. However, is this a good solution? Have i missed something obvious? I dont feel comfterable using a class var in this situation, but i can think of another way!

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:: For example, i would like to call in my mailers like so..

```
    class MyMailer < ApplicatioMailer
      def mail_method_one(email)
        # my call
        remove_custom_header
        mail from: a.format, subject: email.subject
      end
    end
```

And if my method above of setting the class var is valid and sane (which i doubt somehow) can someone explain why as i would be interested how it works and will have to justify it to my lead dev! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what it looks like, `@is_disabled` is not a class variable, it's an instance variable.  Just as the method you defined is defined as an instance class

Note that you're doing...

```
def mail_method_one(email)
```

...not...

```
def self.mail_method_one(email)
```

You can confirm this yourself by stopping execution using the `pry` gem or some other inspection tool...

```
def mail_method_one(email)
  binding.pry
```

And if you examine `self` you'll see you're in an instance of the mailer.

You do call it as a class method, but that's because action mailer uses method_missing to test if the missing class method is actually an instance method and creates a new instance of MessageDelivery passing the class name, the method name and the arguments, and subsequently calls the method on an instance of the mailer class.

Here's the code where it does that...

```
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if action_methods.include?(method_name.to_s)
      MessageDelivery.new(self, method_name, *args)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

You can examine the code here...
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the explanation. Had not though to use Pry. So do you think my implementation is sound in this case then?

Comment: Yes, I like your implementation.  Having the default be a Proc object is a clean way to ensure it gets re-evaluated for every called mail. Others may have a suggestion as to how to improve it, but I'd accept this if I was doing your code review.

Comment: If my answer's been helpful feel free to accept it.

Comment: Absolutly! Thank you so much for the help!